# Why does UserManager.GetUserAsync return null when using JWT?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I have some issues with my .NET CORE 2.1 web api. Im using Identity framework and JWT-tokens for authentication, but whenever I try to get the current user in a controller I get a null reference error.

All settings look fine from what I can see, and I've tried to manually set the key for Identity, but still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Controller:

```
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddIdentity<LoginUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = 
            ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

Claims in token-generation:

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't really explain why this happens, I suppose that this happens because user is not really logged in since JWT is stateless.

But, I managed to get current user thanks to the following snippet :

```
private async Task<AppUser> GetUser()
        => await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.Type, Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))?.Value);
```

Comment: When trying that I get a Exception:


Infinite recursion during resource lookup within System.Private.CoreLib.  This may be a bug in System.Private.CoreLib, or potentially in certain extensibility points such as assembly resolve events or CultureInfo names.  Resource name: Arg_NullReferenceException

Comment: Did you replaced `Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id` by  `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub` ?